# Has-A or Is-A or some strategy pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am developing a web based application which is about tracking Fleet units.

Actually i have already developed the system but in the last six years things changed a bit. Ordinary the software specification was about monitoring **vehicles** in real time and then doing various reports.

How ever during the years we got so many clients in Europe that some of them wanted custom behaviour like inputing the date when various licenses were bought and the date when they expirse so they get a notification for each vehicle when it's time to buy new licence, vignette, insurance and so on..

All seemed to be very good until the time some clients decided that they will buy only 100 GPS devices but they still want to have the rest of 27 (for example) vehicles entered into the system so they get notifications about the vignette, insurance and licence expiration dates. So I had to add new variable like

```
boolean hasGps;
```

Things got even worse. Some clients wanted to attach GPS devices to the trailers of the vehicles so they can monitor them to. So the only way to make this possible is to register the trailers as Vehicles and use the same class where i had to add a new field variable like:

```
boolean isTrailer;
```

Well... again things got really ugly when a company liked the flow meter system that we attach to the vehicles and keep track of the spent fuel so they wanted to have a GPS device and a flow meter device integrated in their GAS station. Again i had to add a new variable like:

```
boolean isGasTank;
```

These days the boss decided that the company will start selling personal tracking devices for security guards and dogs.

So... I decided to re-write the business logic and have the code more clean. However in a real world scenario it seems really difficult to make a good OOP design.

Lets say we have the following fleet units types where a gps device can be attached:

**Vehicle, Trailer, GasStationTank, Ship, Person, Animal**

**All of this units have no behaviour. They only has a state and definition fields.**

The only exception where a gps device may not be attached is the Vehicle object because as i mentioned we enter some ghost vehicles where the only tracking is about the expiration dates of various licences, vignette and insurance.

The Vehicle class has most fields where as the other classes have only **id** and **alias** fields. Some of the vehicle's fields are:

*maxSpeed, fuelPer100, revolutions, flowMeter, fuelNorms. tanks, digitalEvents, analogEvents, parkingDefinition, workingDefinition,*

Here is what I have made so far:

```
public enum FleetUnitType {

    VEHICLE, TRAILER, NONE_GPS_UNIT, GAS_STATTION_TANK, MOVING_NON_VEHICLE_UNIT

}
```

**Abstract class**

```
public abstract class FleetUnit {

    private final String id;

    private String alias;

    private String group;

    private Optional<GpsDevice> gpsDevice;

    private long dateTimeAddedToSystem;


    private FleetUnit linkedFleetUnit;

    public FleetUnit(String id, String alias, String group) {

        if(id == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        else 
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        this.alias = (alias == null ? id : alias);
        this.group = group;

    }

    public abstract FleetUnitType getType();


}
```

**Vehicle class that implements FleetUnit class**

```
public class Vehicle extends FleetUnit {

    public static final double VBAT_CONST = 0.175;

    private int maxSpeed;


    private double urbanFuel100;
    private double suburbanFuel100;
    private double fuelPerHour;


    double maxAccumulatorValueForZeroRevolution;

    private Optional<Revolutions> revolutions;

    private Optional<FlowMeter> flowMeter;

    private Optional<FuelNorm> fuelNorm;

    private final Map<Integer, FuelTank> fuelTanks;


    private final Map<Integer, DigitalEvent> digitalEvents;


    private ParkingDefinition parkingStartDefinition;

    private WorkingDefinition workingStartDefinition;


    public Vehicle(String id, String alias, String group, VehicleMetaData vMetaData) {
        super(id, alias, group);

        this.fuelTanks = new HashMap<>();
        this.digitalEvents = new HashMap<>();

        parkingStartDefinition = ParkingDefinition.ENGINE_OFF;
        workingStartDefinition = WorkingDefinition.ENGINE_ON;
    }



    @Override
    public FleetUnitType getType() {

        if(super.getGpsDevice().isPresent()) return FleetUnitType.VEHICLE; 

        return FleetUnitType.NONE_GPS_DEVICE;
    }


    public static enum EngineState
    {
        MOVING, PARKED, STOPPED, WORKING, CONTACT, UNKNOWN
    }



    public static enum ParkingDefinition
    {
        ENGINE_OFF, TACHOGRAPH
    }

    public static enum WorkingDefinition
    {
        ENGINE_ON, MIN_DISTANCE_TRAVELED
    }

    public static enum MotoHoursCalculation
    {
        ACCUMULATOR, KANSHINA
    }

}
```

As you can see these objects has no behaviour but simply a state which is useful for various reports like how much distance is traveled today or what is the spent fuel and so on...

So finally the question is, should I keep this design and then make the rest of the concrete classes to implement FleetUnit class or I should do something completely different?

Comment: Can you make a spreadsheet where rows are "fleet unit types" and columns are "properties that are valid for a particular type", to help understanding? You can post a screenshot via the stackoverflow imgur service.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i missunderstood the problem, but it looks like these are actually separated entities.

I would personally not use inherence but favor composition.

I would create different classes for each entity implementing an ITrackable interface and simply define the GPS as an object in these entities.

**Using an Interface**
An IReportable interface can also be defined and implemented to add a method to pass the reporting class. something as simple as

```
.report(reportbuilder r)
    { r.report(this) }
```

A visitor pattern should be kept in mind in case different reporters are required later on

Comment: If you want to combine them in a single list?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention the Interface for polymorphism

Comment: But what about the common features are id,alias,group, GpsDevice....

Comment: Are these GPS or Entity properties ? Maybe it makes sense to split it ? Do an abstract class for the entities but keep the GPS related stuff on composition ?

Comment: It's possible...

Comment: the context on with you use this code looks like the source of the problem, and not this snippet itself. Why do you need a GetType method ?

Comment: So instead of base abstract class they should implement an interface. But the interface most probably will have jo methods because this entities only hold a state and have no behaviou.

Comment: The reason i have a method getType is because i want to avoid using instanceof

Comment: by state, you refer to the properties and enums contained in your vehicle class ?

Comment: if you are using " instanceof" i will assume you do it to call entity specific methods. You would be better served by passing a function common to call, for example: .calculate(calculateMethod) ( Visitor pattern )

Comment: Yes. Thats what i mean. These clases simply have no behaviour. Only desription data which is later used to build various reports. Its very big system actually

Comment: hmm. Visitor pattern i would say: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern. Try to keep all your entities as "fleet units" and then use visitor pattern to take care of the class specific functions

Comment: I will check it now. 10x for your time and support. Really appreciate it. I simply want to make the system more organised because its getting too big.

Comment: on the visitor " visit" you can use an abstract factory to decouple the report writing code, thus allowing you to have totally different reports per entity.

Comment: Actually the report building class used to accept fleetunit object... for example DailyRoadlist(Vehicle, startdatetime, enddatetime)...

Comment: probably you can simply pass the Building report class the fleet unit object ? .draw(buildreportclass b) { b.draw(this) } ? No need for Gettypes and enums

Comment: The classes that build the report accept a vehicle object, datetime objects for start and end of a period. Then the method that build the report connects to a database and selects data from table associated with the id of the vehicle object. The range of the selection is based on the datetime objects. Then the data is parsed and packed in an result object which is returned from the call method and then serialized to json ready to be send to the client end visualized with javascript :)

Comment: the solution above with no visitor would probably be the best for now. Simply create a .draw() or .report() method on the fleetunit and pass the report object with a call to self. Later if you need to expand, keep the visitor pattern in mind i would say

Comment: 10x for the info. I will try to recall what i know about visitor pattern.

Comment: Hello, i edited the original response to reflect the problem a bit more. No worries, good i was able to help ! please mark the response as correct if you see that it works :D

Comment: Btw i have 48 different reports. Should i have 48 different methods or one method that accepts report interface

Comment: if you use the same report code for all 48, you just need one. If each report is different, you can either do it via Visitor or simply keep the code above and use an abstract factory to get the correct report object. Please note that my advise my not be the best. its hard without having the full class diagram in mind

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25129/discussion-on-answer-by-eviloop-has-a-or-is-a-or-some-strategy-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would design a property bag of sorts on my base class implementation. It looks like you are using Java so pardon my C#, but I think the idea can still be conveyed.

```
public abstract class FleetUnit
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }

    public FleetUnit()
    {
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}

public class Guard : FleetUnit
{
    protected GpsDevice Gps { get; private set; }

    public Guard(GpsDevice gps)
        : base()
    {
        Gps = gps;
        Properties.Add("Gps", gps);
    }
}
```

Accessing the properties from the base class becomes a TryGetValue call to the dictionary now.

```
public static GpsDevice GetGps(FleetUnit unit)
{
    GpsDevice gps = null;

    unit.Properties.TryGetValue("Gps", out gps);
    return gps; //If no property called Gps exists it returns null.
}
```

This allows you to deal with components of a FleetUnit without needing to know about the implementation of every type. The down side of course is you need to deal with units as a composition of different properties (Gps, Identity, so on)

You could alternatively use interfaces to describe the minimum of features or properties a unit requires to match a method signature which is the more pure OOP impementation, but that would require lots of additional methods to handle each interface and may end up with more complex branching (if-else, switch-case).